# Do infinite manifolds have any Hausdorff measure, maybe of higher dimension?

Tags: measure-theory, dimension-theory-analysis

The usual answer will be obviously, they have "infinite" measure, but what is their measure in higher dimension? Cannot we just say that if you make the manifold's $n$-volume too big, its dimension rises and they obtain $n+1$-volume, like fractals?

Comment: maybe you mean Hausdorff dimension instead of Hausdorff measure?

Comment: Hausdorff measure can be defined for any nonnegative dimension.  For example $$\mathscr{H}^s(\mathbb{R}) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if $s < 1$, and} \\ \infty & \text{if $s \ge 1$,} \end{cases} $$ where $\mathscr{H}^s(X)$ denotes the $s$-dimensional Hausdorff measure of $X$.  In "typical" examples, the Hausdorff measure of a space will be either zero or infinite---it is only when $s$ is the Hausdorff dimension that you can get anything else.